# Nginx: setting subdirectory as file listing, with http auth

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get Nginx set up on a VPS and I'm having a little trouble with the configuration.

I want the `/files` subdirectory to use http authentication. Once authenticated, I want the server to display a simple listing of the files. Right now, the authentication happens correctly, but the system refuses to display the standing listing page, instead returning a 404 on `/files`. When I remove the auth code from the config file, however, it displays the listing just fine.

Setting `autoindex on` in the `/files` location block doesn't work either.

My server blocks from the config file are below. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /srv/http; 
        index  index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;
#       auth_basic "Restricted";
#       auth_basic_user_file /srv/http/files/.htpasswd;
    }

   location /files {
           auth_basic "Restricted";
           auth_basic_user_file /srv/http/files/.htpasswd;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nginx` [chooses one location block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) to process a request. It uses the directives within the location block or inherited from the outer containers.

Your `/files` location lacks a `root` and an `autoindex` directive. These can be replicated within the container, but it is usual to inherit common functionality across sibling `location` containers. For example:

```
root   /srv/http; 
index  index.html index.htm;
autoindex on;

location / {
}

location /files {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/http/files/.htpasswd;
}
```

Or perhaps (depending on your requirements):

```
root   /srv/http; 

location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location /files {
    autoindex on;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/http/files/.htpasswd;
}
```